# Python socket throwing the following error ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, sockets, messaging

I have been trying to create a messaging service in python using sockets. I have written the code to host two connections and allow one to send messages to the other using username and host_addr.

But every time I try to connect the second client and send a message from the first getting the following error.

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Server.py

```
import socket
import _thread as thread

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 1237  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
user_mapping = {}

def on_new_client(conn, addr):
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode()
    print(data)
    print(user_mapping)
    if data[:8] == "username":
        user_mapping[data[9:]] = (addr, data[9:])
    elif data[0] == "@":
        for i in user_mapping.values():
            if i[0] == addr:
                from_user = i[1]
            else:
                str = "user not found"
                conn.sendto(str.encode(), addr)
        str = "%s:%s" % (from_user, data[data.find(":") + 1:])
        conn.sendto(str.encode(), user_mapping[data[1:data.find(":")](0)])
    else:
        pass

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(10)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    thread.start_new_thread(on_new_client,(conn,addr))

s.close()
```

Client.py

```
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 1237  # The port used by the server

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
username = input("Enter user name")
str = "username: %s" % username
s.send(str.encode())
while True:
    message = input(username+">")
    s.send(message.encode())
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data)
```

Was hoping some would could answer why this is happening and guide me to any good links where there is Information on creating a messaging service in python.

Answer (score 0):

Client is sending 2 messages and then receiving one.
But server just listen once and then send one or two packages.

Chronologically:

1. Client sends a package, and server reads it.
2. Then both client and server try to send a package. Both packages that won't meet a listening peer.
3. Then client try to receive a package, but server won't send (he already sent it before) or it may send but its too late because communication is already broken.

Concepts you may implement **always**:

1. If one talk, another one may listen.
2. If a package is mean to be sent, it shall be sent anyway. Dont let a 'if' statment that send package when at 'else' that does not (or viceversa).

==== EDIT ====

About solution:

You need to work with paralel loops.
Take a look at this code https://www.neuralnine.com/tcp-chat-in-python/

He uses two threads on client, one for keep listening for new server updates (messages for other people) and another one to wait input from user.

Comment: moved the listener in the server.py into the while loop so that it listens all the time and also added a s.sendto() in every if and else condition. But still getting the same error. `if data[:8] == "username": user_mapping[data[9:]] = (addr, data[9:]); str = "user sucessfully added"; conn.sendto(str.encode(), addr)

while True:
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    thread.start_new_thread(on_new_client,(conn,addr))`

Comment: I updated my answer with an article that may help you.  :-)